# Why is this Surume Ika (Japanese Flying Squid) discolored? (Ingredient for Ika Somen.)

Tags: squid

I've been very interested in making Ika Somen.  I found both a recipe online, and a recipe in "Pass the recipe", by Hiroko Nomura.  Today I bought a Surume Ika (squid) from the local Japanese market.  When I've purchased squid in the past, I've bought Yari-Ika.

When I cleaned the Surume Ika, the skin was blotched red in places.  The squid didn't smell bad, but also didn't smell ocean-fresh either.  I ended up discarding the squid, just in case.  Would someone know if this discoloration is normal, and if not, what is it?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just killed squid is white, but while death processes continue after defrosting internal organs and inner skin get reddish. It's still possible to eat it even for sashimi though it will be not tasty enough but absolutely fine for cooking.
At least this is according some japanese Q&A sites like this one http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/4199049.html

Most of fresh fish has almost no smell by the way.